# GAE using much more memory than my Java application

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a Java app (Spring Boot) running on Google App Engine; however, I see weird differences between my Java app memory consumption and the dashboard shown by GAE.

In my local machine using a VisualVM I can see it doesn't consume over 100MB even at peak times, and I added a servlet to return the amount of memory used:

```java
@GetMapping("/")
public String index() {
  Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
  long total = rt.totalMemory();
  long free = rt.freeMemory();
  long used = total - free;
  return "Total: " + total / 1024 / 1024 + "MB<br>Used: " + used / 1024 / 1024 + "MB<br>Free: " + free / 1024 / 1024 + "MB";
}
```

my deployed app in GAE right now returns:

```
Total: 91MB
Used: 69MB
Free: 21MB
```

at this same time, the GAE dashboard shows it's consuming around 350MB
[memory dashboard IMG url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dkbjh.png)

Why did that happen? It forces me to use an F2 instance; if I downgrade to an F1, it keeps failing and restarting.

I noticed that once I changed my cronjob from every 30 min to run every 2 min, they started charging me for 40 hours per day in Frontend instances, it was around 16 hours before this change, and I have only 1 instance running. How is that possible?
[instance count img url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9jJw.png)

Thank you

Comment: What are the JVM parameters in the two environments?

Comment: @tgdavies on my app.yml file: runtime: java11
entrypoint: java -Xms64M -Xmx256M -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -jar myjar.jar. On my local I am not setting any JVM parameters running on my Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Firstly, total - free is not an accurate measure of how much memory the JVM is using from the operating system's point of view, which is probably what GAE is reporting. Free heap memory is still allocated to the JVM and is unavailable to other applications. You should look at the total memory your local JVM process is using.

Comment: @tgdavies there is a huge difference between not accurate (~20% off or so) and a difference of 500% - which is exactly the difference i get in a completely different usecase. my guess is a general problem at google...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see these differences is due to the Cloud Console displaying the actual size of the JVM process(which includes stack frames, perm gen space, direct buffers, machine code, etc.) where the memory limit that applies for instances refers to the JVM heap. The runtime uses some heap memory which counted against the total heap usage by the app.

Now, it is important to understand what do these methods do and how to calculate the available memory to allocate:

**totalMemory()**:

> All memory currently used by JVM. It's usually lower than maxMemory
> because JVM allocates memory lazily, "lazily" meaning that some memory
> is allocated initially and used, and, if a new chunk of memory is
> needed, another allocation is done, up to all available memory
> (`maxMemory()`).

---

**maxMemory():**

> Maximum available heap memory (instance size is limited to this
> value).

---

**freeMemory():**

> Portion of memory currently both allocated by JVM and not used.

---

The "real total memory" that can be allocated is:

```
rt.freeMemory() + (rt.maxMemory() - rt.totalMemory())
```

So there can be more memory available than the output of `rt.freeMemory()`.

Comment: i have the same problem with "total" returning 24mb but my dashboard claiming the JVM uses >128mb - and while i can accept "secret native memory usage" as an explanation for some differences, it does not explain a factor of 5 for a test case that just logs a simple message on each request. nothing justifies the use of 128mb.